# Next & previous button with saving earlier record while clicking on previous button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi
I am using one label that displays question & radiobuttonlist for answers. when i click next button next question appears & on  previous click previous question appears but i cant save my earlier answer as it should be display when i click to previous option.
how i can do this?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are showing the current record by clicking radiobuttonlist currently, store the recordid into ViewState and when user is clicking Next or Previous, get the id from ViewState and query the database greater than for next and less than for previous exam question.

Comment: create a dataset of what you need from the database and store a simple index of the row the user is viewing in session or viewstate or whatever you like.  Then your previous and next buttons would simply increment or decrement the index and you can retrieve the next or previous row based on the index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using a database to get the questions, hence, use a database to store and retrieve the values of answers when you click next or previous

Comment: i stored questions & thier correct answers in database but user wil click next & previous many times so how many times i wil save answers selected by user

Comment: @User : Yes , you've to store every time when user clicks back and forth. For Example, if you have a question and 4 answers , you'll be having one field for correct answer and one field for user selected answer. Hence, you'll be storing user selected answer in one of the fields and retrieve that field as per the question id. Hope this makes you clear